# Search for range Latitude/Longitude coordinates

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation

This script works, but I am sure there is a better way to approach this. I have already tried storing them using the MySQL gis functionality any other suggestions would be helpful.

```
$vicinity = .001;

$lat_ceiling = floatval($lat) + floatval($vicinity);
$lat_floor =  floatval($lat) - floatval($vicinity);
$lng_ceiling = floatval($lng) + floatval($vicinity);
$lng_floor =  floatval($lng) - floatval($vicinity);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `geolocations` WHERE".
            "`latitude` <= '".$lat_ceiling."' AND `latitude` >= '". $lat_floor ."' AND `longitude` <= '".$lng_ceiling."' AND `longitude` >= '". $lng_floor ."'  ";
```

Comment: Tell us what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: This should work fine for small distances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some version of what you are doing is right but I think you probably want to use the actual geometry types, especially if you are on MyISAM and can create an R-Tree spatial index. You can have columns with any supported type (ie `point`, `polygon`), or the catchall `geometry` type:

```
mysql> create table spatial_table (id int, my_spots point, my_polygons geometry);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
```

Then query and update with WKT syntax:

```
mysql> insert into spatial_table values (1, GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)'), GeomFromText('POLYGON((1 1, 2 2, 0 2, 1 1))'));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into spatial_table values (1, GeomFromText('POINT(10 10)'), GeomFromText('POLYGON((10 10, 20 20, 0 20, 10 10))') );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

You can then do your query (ie vicinity), against the minimum bounding rectangle of a linestring with terminating points point1 = longitude - increment, lon - increment, y = longitude + increment, latitude + increment, ie here with a +- of 1:

```
mysql> select * from spatial_table where MBRContains(GeomFromText('LINESTRING(9 9, 11 11)'), my_spots);
+------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | my_spots                  | my_polygons                                                                       |
+------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 |              $@      $@ |                    $@      $@      4@      4@              4@      $@      $@ |
+------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This will perform much better than doing arithmetic on a bunch of floats representing longitude and latitude. BTW at about the location of San Francisco the following constants work pretty well for converting between km and degrees longitude and latitude (ie, if you want clean square maps of Santa Cruz):

```
lonf 0.01132221938
latf 0.0090215040
```

That is, (x +- 2*lonf, y +- 2*latf) gives you the relevant `$lat_floor` etc values for a 2km wide boy around your point of interest.

Comment: Do you know if the geo extension is faster then using my method or compute a spatial index by your own? What is the geo extension use to index the coordinate? A z-curve? A hilbert curve?

Comment: A quick lesson in R-Tree spatial index and mysql MBRContains clarified a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please follow up with an answer to my next question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115106/convert-lat-lng-pairs-using-geomfromtextpoint1-1-from-one-table-and-insert

Comment: The geo extension on MyISAM is an R-Tree, not sure whether Hilbert R-Tree or something else -- but if you just add a spatial index on InnoDB it actually gives you a B-Tree, which is mostly ok for looking up a single point and not much else. If I was going to try to roll my own geo index I would probably use some kind of geohash for simplicity which I think would behave like your last example.

Comment: @bvmou: geohash is wellknow algorithm used by xkbd and it's some sort of a z-curve. I can show you how to use a Hilbert curve and a quadkey to get all locations of an incomplete quadkey.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything really wrong with the way you're doing it, but this might be a little cleaner:

```
SELECT *
FROM `geolocations`
WHERE
    `latitude` BETWEEN $lat - $vicinity AND $lat + $vicinity
    AND
    `longitude` BETWEEN $lng - $vicinity AND $lng + $vicinity
```

Answer (score 0):

[PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) is an add-on for PostgreSQL databases, for managing geographic data. It has a distance-function: http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.3/ch06.html#id2574517

Comment: And reading would help: "I have … tried storing them using MySQL gis … **any other suggestions would be helpful**"

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an approximation of the harvesine formula maybe you want to use a spatial index or a space-filling-curve. A sfc is a quadtree and fractal like data structure reducing the 2d complexity to a 1d complexity. It's a curve that completley fills the space and a clever algorithm to subdivide the map. Instead of computing the index you can also nest the tiles and accumulate a quadkey and search in this key with the standard mysql string operators. For example if you have a quadkey 11111222233334444 you can search for 1111* to find all key => location pairs from this node and below or right from it.