# Convert lat/lng pairs using GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)') and insert in another column

Tags: mysql

In my previous question [Search for range Latitude/Longitude coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112661/search-for-range-latitude-longitude-coordinates)   My solution was to create the table below.

```
mysql> select * from spatial_table where MBRContains(GeomFromText('LINESTRING(9 9, 11 11)'), my_spots);
+------+---------------------------------+
| id   | my_spots    | my_polygons       |
+------+-------------+-------------------+
|    1 |  $@      $@     $@      $@      |
+------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Now I need to convert and move my existing lat/lng pairs in the table below to spatial_table. How would I structure my query to acheive this? I am currently using the queries below to insert.

```
mysql> insert into spatial_table values (1, GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)'), GeomFromText('POLYGON((1 1, 2 2, 0 2, 1 1))'));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into spatial_table values (1, GeomFromText('POINT(10 10)'), GeomFromText('POLYGON((10 10, 20 20, 0 20, 10 10))') );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Existing table:

```
+-------------+---------+--------+-----------+----- ------+-------------+--------------+
| location_id | country | region |  city     | latitude   | longitude   |     name     |
+=============|=========|========|===========|============|=============|==============|
|   316625    |   US    |   CA   | Santa Cruz|  37.044799 | -122.102096 |  Rio Theatre |
+-------------+---------+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the secret recipe to success :)
My original table:

```
mysql> describe gls;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| location_id | int(255)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| country     | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |       |
| region      | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |       |
| city        | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |       |
| latitude    | float(13,10) | NO   |     |         |       |
| longitude   | float(13,10) | NO   |     |         |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

step 1: Add new POINT column

```
mysql> alter table gls add my_point point;
Query OK, 247748 rows affected (4.77 sec)
Records: 247748  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Step 2: Update my_point with values from lat/lng fields.

```
UPDATE gls SET my_point = PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',gls.longitude,' ',gls.latitude,')'));
```

Step 3: check

```
mysql> select aswkt(my_point) from gls where city='Santa Cruz';
+--------------------------------------+
| aswkt(my_point)                      |
+--------------------------------------+
| POINT(-122.1020965576 37.0447998047) |
| POINT(-66.25 -12.2833003998)         |
| POINT(-2.3499999046 42.6666984558)   |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is this Correct POINT(',gls.longitude,' ',gls.latitude,')? are lat and lon transposed? ----- is it not POINT(',gls.latitude,' ',gls.longitude ,')

Comment: POINT(LON,LAT) is correct. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-class-point.html

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a table like this:

```
mysql> select * from spatial_table;
+------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------+
| id   | my_spots                  | my_polygons                                                                       | lon     | lat    |
+------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------+
|    1 |              ??      ??   |                    ??      ??       @       @               @      ??      ??     | -122.11 | -37.11 |
|    1 |              $@      $@ |                    $@      $@      4@      4@              4@      $@      $@ | -122.11 | -37.11 |
+------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want to make a geometry column with the lon lat values (as points only, syntax is a little different for other kinds of geometries), you can do this:

```
mysql> alter table spatial_table add column (go_slugs geometry);
```

This is a geometry type, if it is all single locations you could make the column type `point`. Then just update the new column:

```
mysql> update spatial_table set go_slugs = point(lon, lat);
```

Use the aswkt function to get human readable data to confirm this is correct:

```
mysql> select aswkt(go_slugs) from spatial_table;
+-----------------------------------------------+
| aswkt(go_slugs)                               |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| POINT(-122.11000061035156 -37.11000061035156) |
| POINT(-122.11000061035156 -37.11000061035156) |
| POINT(-123.4000015258789 37.79999923706055)   |
+-----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your guidance opened many new paths for me. exactly why I joined SO. Its difficult to articulate what I need sometimes and Ireally appreciate when others can make sense of my questions.

Comment: This works flawlessly to display layer in geoserver using data from MySQL. Thank you!