# golang - mysql driver - database functions

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I have created a struct to store spatial types and I have created a scan function to help query rows in my database.  I am having issues inserting this type.

I can insert data using the following sql;

```
INSERT INTO 'table' ('spot') VALUES (GeomFromText('POINT(10 10)'));
```

If I use Value interface in *database/sql/driver*;

> type Value interface{}
>
> Value is a value that drivers must be able to handle. It is either nil or an instance of one of these types:
>
> int64
>
> float64
>
> bool
>
> []byte
>
> string   [*] everywhere except from Rows.Next.
>
> time.Time

And use this code;

```
func (p Point) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return "GeomFromText('" + p.ToWKT() + "')", nil
}
```

I end up with the following sql statement going to the database;

```
INSERT INTO 'table' ('spot') VALUES ('GeomFromText('POINT(10 10)')');
```

The issue being that the function *GeomFromText* is in quotes.  Is there a way to avoid this scenario? I am using gorm and trying to keep raw sql queries to a minimum.

The mysql type being used on the database end is a *point*.

Comment: typically the table names and columns would be wrapped in back-ticks or nothing. For instance, a back-tick would be spectacular if the column name was `limit` or `My Column` or `this-thing`

Comment: Have you tried keeping the function call `GeomFromText` in the query and have your `Point` `Value` method return `p.ToWKT()`?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I suppose I didn't make my difficulties clear. I have no problem with my schema and I know how to insert spatial data, it's more of a sql driver issue. I know that `db.Exec("INSERT INTO 'table' ('spot') VALUES (GeomFromText($1))", p.ToWKT())` will work however I am trying to avoid using raw sql queries usch as that. I know that the reason my code is failing is because `func (p Point) Value()` is returning a string and my MySQL function is being placed in quotes.  Is there a way of using this interface and have only part of the string placed in quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the two urls below where the concept was poached from

### Schema

```
-- http://howto-use-mysql-spatial-ext.blogspot.com/

create table Points
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    name VARCHAR(20) not null, 
    location Point NOT NULL, 
    description VARCHAR(200) not null, 
    SPATIAL INDEX(location),
    key(name)
)engine=MyISAM; -- for use of spatial indexes and avoiding error 1464

-- insert a row, so we can prove Update later will work
INSERT INTO Points (name, location, description) VALUES 
( 'point1' , GeomFromText( ' POINT(31.5 42.2) ' ) , 'some place');
```

### Update statement

```
-- concept borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7135890
UPDATE Points 
set location = PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',13.33,' ',26.48,')'))
where id=1;
```

### Verify

```
select * from points;
```

(when you open the Value Editor to see the blob, the point is updated)

So, the takeaway is to play with the `concat()` inside of the update statement.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Is this writing raw SQL query? I don't understand how you make it work.