# Insert a POINT() value in mysql using Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, mysql, point, fat-free-framework, geopoints

I need to insert a POINT value into my MySQL table using Fat Free Framework. I was hoping to do this using the F3 Mapper, but I got the impression that is not possible.

So I tried to use $db-exec()

This is my current code, based on various searches here and on google.

```
$geopoint = "POINT($lat $long)";
$db->exec("INSERT INTO event_dates ('eventGeoPoint') VALUES ($geopoint)");
```

This throws an error:

```
PDOStatement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '52.8583742))' at line 1
```

I have also tried

```
 $db->exec("INSERT INTO event_dates ('eventGeoPoint') VALUES (GeomFromText($geopoint))");
```

Please tell me how to correctly insert a POINT() value into my database using Fat Free Framework, either the mapper or exec

Comment: was your problem solved ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your `INSERT` statement, which you are mixed with `UPDATE` statement.

```
INSERT INTO mytable SET myGeoPoint = 'GeomFromText($geopoint)
```

should be

```
 INSERT INTO mytable(myGeoPoint) values (GeomFromText($geopoint))
```

Also, you need to use Prepared Statement to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: Right, silly me! Still I changed the statement and tried 

"INSERT INTO mytable ('GeoPoint') VALUES ($geopoint)" 

and 

"INSERT INTO mytable ('GeoPoint') VALUES (GeomFromText($geopoint))" 

but both still give PDOStatement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '52.8583742))' at line 1

Does this have to do with the F3 way of handling inserts? Or is the statement still wrong?

Comment: @vanMeerdervoort OK, what is `GeomFromText ` ?

Comment: Its a MySQL function to format point data. I did find the answer though, since you pointed out well that my syntax was wrong. Turns out it's quite an elaborate syntax ;) See my own answer

Answer (score 0):

Searching on after @Ravi's comments I found the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115106/convert-lat-lng-pairs-using-geomfromtextpoint1-1-and-insert-in-another-col).

I changed my statement to

```
$result= $db->exec("INSERT INTO mytable (GeoPoint) VALUES (PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',$lat,' ',$long,')')))");
```

And it works!